# Cannot access VM unless logged into Elementary (get blank screen)

Tags: virtualization

I am running the latest Elementary o/s (as of this writing), my situation is that I am a software developer and still need Windows to be accessible while remote.  I have a Windows 10 VM set up using VMWare workstation.

My issue is that when I attempt to RDC remotely, I can connect to the VM, but the screen is black.

The ONLY way i have been able to remedy this is by using TeamViewer, logging in remotely, then doing RDC to the Windows VM again. Also, i seem to have the same issue with vnc4server (remote in just gives me black screen).

I am trying desperately to replace my default Windows machine with Elementary, any thoughts on how can I fix this?

.

thanks :-)